# Merge single objects and list of objects into a single list of objects in Java

Tags: java, list, arraylist, java-8, java-stream

Given a list of objects

```
// ["A", ["B", null, "C"], "D", ["E"], [], null, "F"];
List<Object> objects = Arrays.asList("A", Arrays.asList("B", null, "C"), "D", Arrays.asList("E"), Arrays.asList(), null, "F");
```

Is there a simple way to combine the non-null values into a single list `["A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F"]`?

Some of you insist the post has to show what was tried

```
objects.stream().map(o -> {
        if (o instanceof List) {
            return ((List) o).stream();
        } else return objects.stream();
    }).filter(Objects::nonNull).collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

obviously the above didn't work.

Comment: May we ask how you ended up with this jagged list data structure?  It almost feels like it came from JSON maybe.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen It was from a map of objects and then flattened into a list of objects, but then you would want to know how the map comes from? So yes JSON if that helps?

Comment: `List<Object>` !! You should be checking all possible type then. What about the rest of them? JSON still treats number differently, right?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If there are only two levels of nesting, not deeper lists within lists recursively,
then here's one way to flatten it:

```
List<String> flat = objects.stream()
  .filter(Objects::nonNull)
  .flatMap(v -> {
    if (v instanceof String) {
      return Stream.of((String) v);
    }
    return ((List<String>) v).stream().filter(Objects::nonNull);
  })
  .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

If there can be deeper levels of nesting recursively,
then you can wrap the above in a function and apply it recursively (thanks [@Holger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2711488/holger) for making it more compact):

```
List<String> flatten(List<?> objects) {
  return objects.stream()
    .filter(Objects::nonNull)
    .flatMap(v -> v instanceof String
      ? Stream.of((String) v)
      : flatten((List<?>) v).stream())
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

Comment: Thanks @janos! Do you think you are up for the challenge to do a recursive version?

Comment: Or shorter: `List<String> flatten(List<?> objects) {  return objects.stream() .filter(Objects::nonNull) .flatMap(v -> v instanceof String? Stream.of((String)v): flatten((List<?>)v).stream()) .collect(Collectors.toList());  }`